# Animation - game object not staying in place

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm trying to animate a simple attack animation for my 3D character, but I can't seem to get the weapon to stay where I put it. I've tried saving the location, rotation and scale using Ctrl + A, keying the frame, moving the arm back for the recoil, saving the keyframes, moving the weapon back with it, applying the rotation, location and scale, and adding the keyframe. However, the weapon just goes back to the centre of the grid, looking like the chaeacter is standing on it.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I sort this out?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: you've given your object an animation, so it obeys. In the Dopesheet press the Only Include Channels button (arrow), select the weapon, remove the attached action you see with the X button.

Comment: I only see LocRotScale at the bottom, but it only has 1 keyframe. If I add another one, it messes up the character or the placement of the character or weapon. I've selected Only Include Channels.

Comment: LocRotScale means you have created an animation that also influence the LocRotScale of the object, so if you give this animation to either a cube or an armature it will influence their LocRotScale, so select the weapon and close the animation with X

Comment: you must have created this animation for your armature and given it to the weapon by mistake. What do you want to do with this weapon exactly? If you want it to follow the hand, you should parent it to the hand bone, something like that...

Comment: I take it you mean the animation in the NLA...? There's nothing in the Dopesheet from what I can see.

Comment: no, select the weapon and in the Dopesheet you can see that there's an animation associated with the weapon called "Action". If you don't want this animation to be associated to the weapon (which seems logic as it looks like it was an animation made for an armature) press the X button on the right of the name, now your weapon doesn't have anymore animation, is it not what you want?

Comment: Oh. The Action one is supposed to be for the character's entire action animation. So the character's movement and the weapon's movement.

Comment: I think I've got it though. I've made the character's animation/movement separate under Erif_Rig and the gun's movement under Ice Gun.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the best way to organize your animation, what is your weapon supposed to do right now? If you give it an action that asks it to stay put (like the action called Action) it will stay put.

Comment: Hmm. At the moment, I'm just doing a recoil animation as though the weapon has been fired. I'm guessing, but correct me if I'm wrong, I need to create and animate a projectile/bullet as its own object so it can be used to hit enemies. To be honest, I don't know why it's called Action as it's supposed to be called 'Attack'. The whole thing is supposed to be the character's attack animation - movement and weapon movement combined.

Comment: generally a weapon is supposed to follow the hand movement, so why don't you make it child of the hand bone for example? If you want a bullet, it's another object, it can even be a child of the gun if you want it to follow as well... but to give your gun the same action as your armature is strange...

Comment: Believe me, that was unintentional lol.

Comment: Okay, I *think* this time, I've got it. I've parented the gun to the hand bone. Although, it annoys me that the newly created Action I make, such as Attack in this case, keeps being de-selected and potentially messes things up. I think that's how some animations are ending up on other strips or are cropping up in places I don't want. :-\

Comment: Another thing though: what would be the best thing to do to get rid of the gun from appearing in my other animations/strips now that it's parented?

Comment: some actions keep de-selected? not sure to understand. And what do you mean "get rid of the gun"? Just create your action for your armature, the gun will follow as it is now parented, if you want to create animation for the gun (like for example a bullet which is parented to the gun that is projected), create it, just don't give your gun some actions you've created for your armature and vice-versa  ;)

Comment: In the Dopesheet. At the moment it's on my Attack Action. But the amount of times I go back to the Dopesheet and then find it's gone back to Idle or Walk or something. No idea why that's happened or what I've done.
With getting rid of the gun - I don't want it in the character's hand or in the scene during the idle, walk and jump animations.
If I have the bullet a child of the gun object, how would I be able to get that to hit an enemy? Surely if it was it's own object, I'd be able to attach a script to it?

Comment: yes at the beginning it's a bit hard to understand the logic between the actions, the dopesheet and NLA, etc... About your bullet, make it a child of your gun, which is a child of the hand. So when he shoots you just need to activate an action (in the NLA) that propels the bullet out of the gun, not so complicated

Comment: I also find that one minute an animation works and then the next, it doesn't. Selecting an Action - Idle, Walk etc. - doesn't do anything, or play the corredsponding animation. Or I click on the star to isolate an animation and it doesn't play.

Answer (score 2):

In the *Dopesheet* press the *Only Include Channels* button (arrow icon, allows to only see the keyframes of the selected object), select the weapon, you'll see if your object has an action assigned. You've given your gun an action called "Action", this action has bones keyframes, so I guess it is supposed to be used by your armature, not your gun. And this action also has *LocRotScale* keyframes, your gun will be affected by those *LocRotScale*. It makes no sense to use such an action, don't give any action to your gun (except for example propelling a bullet), your gun should rather follow the hand of your armature. So in the *Dopesheet* remove the action with the X button on the right of its name (*Unlink this Action*). Now your gun is free from any action. Now parent it to the hand bone, so that it will be moved by the hand, it's much more logical.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not seeing that option. I go to the Dopesheet, select the weapon object, but no object shows. If I select the hand holding the gun, the only options I see are the quaternion rotations and scales etc.

Comment: what option can't you see? no object show: what are you talking about? please follow exactly what I say, if you enable the Only Include Channel option in the Dopesheet and select an object you'll see if there is an action that has been assigned to it, if I open your file I can see that the action called Action has been assigned to your gun, which makes no sense, as I suppose Action is supposed to be assigned to your armature. You need to understand that you can create an animation for an object and assign it to any other object in your scene.

Comment: Of course your gun doesn't have any bone so it won't take account of the bone keyframes but Action also have LocRotScale keyframes, so your gun is affected by those...

Comment: I'll upload the latest save file I have.

Comment: Yep, I clicked on Only Include Channel, but I don't see any difference. I'll upload a screenshot.

Comment: the difference with this option is that you won't see all the keyframes of all the objects in the Dopesheet, you'll only see the ones of the object(s) or bone(s) selected, that's all   ;)

Comment: I've opened your new file, selected your gun... have you a reason to assign it the animation called Attack? I'm not sure to understand...

Comment: Yeah. It’s supposed to be a part of my attack animation. How would you set it up?

Comment: why do you want to assign an animation to your gun, other than for example the bullet propelling? Your attack animation is supposed to animate your armature, not the gun, the gun will be animated by the hand of the armature, don't give any action to the gun, I thought you understood y explanation

Comment: So did I... I mean, I parented the gun to the hand's armature... I thought the whole animation was assigned to the armature...

Comment: the action of an object can be assigned to any other object of your scene, here for example you've assigned the action called Attack to your gun, why that? Enable the arrow option, select the gun, remove the action Attack. Anyway I guess it is not playing anymore because you've parented the gun to the hand, but there was no reason to give your gun this Attack action

Comment: Right. I believe I understand now. That'll be why whenever I've selected an Action from the list, it hasn't always worked. It's because I will have selected the model without thinking/realising instead of the armature, and therefore it hasn't worked. That'll be why the Action has been getting assigned to the gun itself.

Comment: Only thing I haven't got yet, and is the last thing I need to do, is remove the gun from the model in the idle, walk and jump animations.

Comment: I should probably start a new thread, but I probably wouldn't get a reply. :-\
How exactly can I keyframe the projectile's movement from the gun without the Attack Action being applied to it. It needs to be a part of the Attack Action, but if I have that Action open and select the projectile to animate it, it's going to apply that Action to it.

Comment: create an action for the bullet itself and use the NLA to start it whenever you want

Comment: Okay, thanks. Two final things: I would like to add some particles as the projectile fires, but would I be better using an image for that? Also, what would be the best light for a muzzle flash? I have got a Hemi...
Thanks again

Comment: You should open a new topic for this question, and don't forget to show some pictures of what you want